# Problem using smart home on Raspberry pi with integrated Alexa not certified?

Tags: raspberry-pi, alexa-voice-service, alexa-smart-home-skill

I have installed Alexa Voice Service (AVS) Device SDK on a Raspberry Pi.

I want to use smart home to turn on a led on my raspberry pi via the Alexa command.

To do this, I followed the following tutorial: https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/blogs/alexa/device-makers/2020/04/create-a-sample-alexa-built-in-disco-ball-with-smart-home-for-av

When I ask Alexa to turn on my led, the answer is "this feature is only supported by Alexa integrated devices".

I wait for Alexa to execute my request.
Is it really impossible to use this feature until the device is certified? Or have I done something wrong?

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your observation is correct. When you create your own AVS device using the AVS Device SDK, for example installing The AVS Device SDK on a Raspberry Pi, not all AVS features will be available.

That said, if your intent is to bring a product to market and would like access to a particular AVS feature, you may be interested in hiring a Systems Integrator (SI). Systems Integrators offer hardware modules, software, and services to help you easily integrate Alexa into connected products. For more information and a list of available SIs for hire, please visit the below resource:

- https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/alexa/solution-providers/systems-integrators

Additionally, if you would like help with manufacturing an end device, you may be interested in hiring an Original Design Manufacturer (ODM). ODMs provide custom hardware and software design, development, certification, and manufacturing. For more information and a list of available ODMs for hire, please visit the below resource:

- https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/alexa/solution-providers/odm-solutions